# Possible to copy branches/pages of TYPO3 6.2 into existing website?

Tags: typo3, data-migration, typo3-6.2.x

I am new to TYPO3 and got a problem. I have an existing website (6.2) and an old site (4.5).

Problem is that the old site has a lot of pages which should be migrated into the new site. The existing pages of the old site contain only regular content records. I want to avoid to copy hundreds of pages manually.

My idea is to upgrade the old site from 4.5 to 6.2. And then somehow copy the existing branches/pages eg. with help of sql? Does someone has experience with it?

If this might not work is it possible to copy at least the structure of the branches/pages? Means the content needs to be copied manually but at least page title, url etc. can be copied by sql?

Comment: Check the system extension "impexp". It should add options "export" and "import" to the context menu of the page tree, which you can use to export the page tree from the old site and import it to the new one.

Comment: sounds good. I found this bug report https://forge.typo3.org/issues/60540 Seems like tool is working for 4.5 to 6.2.